# How to select last two characters of a string

Tags: javascript, string

I need to select last two characters from the variable, whether it is digit or letters.

For example:

```
var member = "my name is Mate";
```

I would like to show last two letters from the string in the `member` variable.

Answer (score 642, accepted):

You can pass a negative index to [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice). That will indicate an offset from the end of the set.

```
var member = "my name is Mate";

var last2 = member.slice(-2);

alert(last2); // "te"
```

Comment: `slice()` reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Answer (score 29):

EDIT: 2020: use `string.slice(-2)` as others say - see below.

now 2016 just `string.substr(-2)` should do the trick  (not **substring**(!))

taken from MDN

> Syntax
>
> `str.substr(start[, length])`
>
> Parameters
>
> start
>
> Location at which to begin extracting characters. **If a negative number is given, it is treated as strLength + start** where strLength is
>   the length of the string (for example, if start is -3 it is treated as
>   strLength - 3.) length
>       Optional. The number of characters to extract.

**EDIT 2020**

MDN says

> Warning: Although String.prototype.substr(…) is not strictly
>   deprecated (as in "removed from the Web standards"), it is considered
>   a legacy function and should be avoided when possible. It is not part
>   of the core JavaScript language and may be removed in the future.

Comment: "Microsoft's JScript does not support negative values for the start index. To use this feature in JScript, you can use the following code..." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr (whereas for slice they don't have any polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

Comment: note that JScript is not inside the browser, it's a scripting language for working with Windows Script Host automation mainly (similar to VBScript), so it's logical that at its time it didn't include such methods.Newer Windows versions promote PowerShell, with a cryptic syntax. Anyway the comment was on slice being better candidate than substr in the case of JScript, since it supports negative indices https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/6w1bzf9f%28v%3dvs.84%29

Answer (score 26):

Try this, note that you don't need to specify the end index in `substring`.

```
var characters = member.substr(member.length -2);
```

Comment: Your original answer was probably more appropriate. According to [MDN's `substr` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr), *"Microsoft's JScript does not support negative values for the start index."*

Answer (score 18):

The following example uses `slice()` with negative indexes

```js
var str = 'my name is maanu.';
console.log(str.slice(-3));     // returns 'nu.' last two
console.log(str.slice(3, -7)); // returns 'name is'
console.log(str.slice(0, -1));  // returns 'my name is maanu'
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try

```
member.substr(member.length-2);
```

Comment: You missed member.length from your starting index :)

Comment: Ah cool, I've updated my answer to reflect, thanks T.J and Ibu :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Pretty sure the negative index as a starting position doesn't work for IE8 and lower.

Comment: @amnotiam: **Thank you,** very good to know! I just [tested](http://jsbin.com/epogey), and sure enough, **didn't** work on IE7 or IE8 (and so presumably wouldn't work on IE6). IE9 in standards mode was fine (but not compat). I never use `substr`, and now I wish I could find the thread where some smug git gave me a hard time for that (and in particular not using negative indexes) -- I can now justify it! :-)

Answer (score 3):

If it's an integer you need a part of....

```
var result = number.toString().slice(-2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use substring, not jQuery, to do this.

Try something like this:

```
member.substring(member.length - 2, member.length)
```

W3Schools (not official, but occasionally helpful):   http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Adding MDN link as requested by commenter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Comment: please provide links to an official documentation such as MSDN or MDN, not w3fools :)

Comment: w3schools is not "official" but generally has reliable information. MSDN is official, but is IE specific and does not have anything to do with Firefox, Safari, etc.

Comment: added the link to the comment as you were posting this

Answer (score 2):

```
var member = "my name is maanu";
```

`var answer=member.substring(0,member.length - 2);`

```
alert(answer);
```

Comment: What does the code do? Please write an explanation of what this achieves.

Comment: To be fair, the question is very specific about what the code needs to do, so an answer consisting of (in essence) one line of code is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: code output will be 'nu'    . Take last 2 charecter from word .

Comment: Seems to me like the code output will be "my name is maa" (everything ~except~ the last two letter), which is not what the question asked for, if I understood it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

**Shortest:**

```
str.slice(-2)
```

**Example:**

```js
const str = "test";
const last2 = str.slice(-2);

console.log(last2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Slice can be used to find the substring. When we know the indexes we can use an alternative solution like index wise adder. Both are taking roughly the same time for execution.

```js
const primitiveStringMember = "my name is Mate";

const objectStringMember = new String("my name is Mate");
console.log(typeof primitiveStringMember);//string
console.log(typeof objectStringMember);//object


/* However when we use . operator to string primitive type, JS will wrap up the string with object. That's why we can use the methods String object type for the primitive type string.
*/

//Slice method
const t0 = performance.now();
slicedString = primitiveStringMember.slice(-2);//te
const t1 = performance.now();
console.log(`Call to do slice took ${t1 - t0} milliseconds.`);


//index vise adder method
const t2 = performance.now();
length = primitiveStringMember.length
neededString = primitiveStringMember[length-2]+primitiveStringMember[length-1];//te
const t3 = performance.now();
console.log(`Call to do index adder took ${t3 - t2} milliseconds.`);
```