# Formatting Date.getHours(), Date.getMinutes(), Date.getSeconds()

Tags: javascript

I wanna format the output after getting the values of `Date.getHours()`, `Date.getMinutes()` and `Date.getSeconds()`.

Here is the long way:

```
var dt = new Date();
var HH = dt.getHours();
var mm = dt.getMinutes();
var ss = dt.getSeconds();

HH = HH < 10 ? '0' + HH : HH;
mm = mm < 10 ? '0' + mm : mm;
ss = ss < 10 ? '0' + ss : ss;
```

My question: How can I compress the last part to `.toString('D2')` function?

What I wanna archive:

```
var dt = new Date();
var HH = dt.getHours().toString('D2');
var mm = dt.getMinutes().toString('D2');
var ss = dt.getSeconds().toString('D2');
```

p/s: `.toString('D2')` is same meaning with [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx). Like C# syntax:

```
int i = 1;
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("D2")); // output: 01
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to output integers with leading zeros in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-integers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript)

Comment: You can copy&paste the `printf` for javascript from somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think Javascript has that kind of support. You would need to either write an ancillary function or install a library.

The closest I can think of for a one-liner is

```
("0"+dt.getSeconds()).slice(-2)
```

after [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10741958/1428679).

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following should work:

```
var HH = ('0'+dt.getHours().toString()).slice(-2);
```

Similar approach for the others.
You can also avoid explicitly calling `toString`, thus:

```
var HH = ('0'+dt.getHours()).slice(-2);
```

Comment: you don't need toString, as you already converted it to a string by concatenating to '00'. You also don't need '00', '0' is enough

Comment: I was just writing the first part. You are right about '00', thank you (I've used '00' because it is the desired length, but `getHours` ever returns something actually).

Answer (score 1):

```
var dt = new Date();
var today = dt.toJSON().slice(0, 10);
var time = dt.toJSON().slice(11, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This function should be able to provide the solution to your problem. While this is not exactly the way you would like to do it, it is the easiest.

```js
function decimalFormat(precision, number) {
  if (arguments.length !== 2)
    throw new Error("Invalid number of arguments!");
  else if (typeof precision !== "number" || typeof number !== "number")
    throw new TypeError("Invalid parameter type!");
  var zeros = "0";
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.abs(precision); i++)
    zeros += "0";
  return (zeros + number.toString()).slice(-1 * (Math.abs(precision)));
}

alert(decimalFormat(10, 21));
alert(decimalFormat(2, 5221));
alert(decimalFormat(4, 221));
```